# Inhibit suspend under Gnome

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, debian, suspend

I have enabled the gnome (2.30) screensaver and set it to suspend the machine after so many minutes. It works fine!

Now, there are cases that I want to use the machine in "server mode". That is, there would not be physical activity on the machine while it serves files, or acts as a ssh terminal. As there is not physical activity, the machine would suspend after the time elapses. Is there a utility/script/something to inhibit suspend?

ps. I had no luck with the dbus/python scripts do circulate in the Internet, nor is the "inhibit" applet anywhere available in my gnome distribution. I use ubuntu lucid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent the computer going to sleep automatically with these commands:

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-power-manager/timeout/sleep_computer_battery --type int 0
gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-power-manager/timeout/sleep_computer_ac --type int 0
```

It will set the corresponding gconf database keys, the first one determines after which time the computer goes to sleep when it's idle and on **battery**, the second one when it's on **ac plug**. Setting them at 0 disables automatic sleep (you may not want this behaviour when on battery). To set it back to, say, a 30 minute delay, you do:

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-power-manager/timeout/sleep_computer_ac --type int 1800
```

You can browse the available gconf keys with `gconf-editor`, it may interest you.

Comment: Good answer. I will check it out. Both keys are named sleep_computer_ac, I suppose one should be sleep_computer_bat or something?

Comment: sorry, the right key is sleep_computer_battery. Edited.

Comment: I am afraid it did not work. I double checked that the suggested command changes the value using gconf-editor (and it did it does) but still the machine sleeps.

Comment: Alternatively you can do:
`gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-power-manager/actions/sleep_type_ac --type string nothing; gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-power-manager/actions/sleep_type_battery --type string nothing`
Does it work?

Answer (score 1):

GConf and gconftool-2 no longer work and have been [deprecated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GConf) as of Gnome 3.

[GSettings / dconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dconf#GSettings) are what you are looking for now.

**Get current value:**

> gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout

**Inhibit suspend:**

> gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 0

**Useful command examples**

> gsettings list-schemas
>
> gsettings describe org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the "suspend after..." to its appropriate state manually, using the scripting language of your choice. I suspect this setting is stored via the gconf service, there is a python-gconf module that will allow you to adjust settings in this 'configuration service' programmatically (it's basically the Windows registry for Linux). [Here's a tutorial](http://www.mikedesjardins.net/content/category/gconf/) on using python-gconf. You can use the Configuration Editor tool to hunt around gconf and see where the appropriate setting might be.